# Duplicate Character Counter for an Alphanumeric

Tags: python, for-loop, counting

I am writing a short piece of code to practice learning python. Note I am not worried about error handling right now just the functional piece.

User to input an alphanumeric string, output to show count for each character in the input

```
 input = "poop"
 desired output = p:2, o:2
 current output = p:1, o:1
```

I have written everything up to a histogram and a for loop to collect the count of each character, but when my for loop runs I only ever return a count of 1. Can someone help me with some direction as to why the characters aren't getting counted more than once?

My code is below.

```
    s = input("Enter alphanumeric: ")
    print(s)

    l = []

    for char in s:
        l.append(char)
    print(l)

    letter_histogram = dict.fromkeys(l,0)
    print(letter_histogram)

    for char in letter_histogram:
        letter_histogram[char] = letter_histogram[char] + 1
    print(letter_histogram)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be iterating over the user input, not your dictionary

```
for char in s:
    letter_histogram[char] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes obvious sense. Another mistake another lesson learned. I'll give this a check when the time restraint is up.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach better, it's more readable, you can use a `set` for grouping unique characters and then `.count` method of string for finding number of occurrences, for example this:

```py
sample = "poop"
letters = set(sample)
histogram = {
    letter: sample.count(letter) for letter in letters
}
print(histogram)

>>> {'p': 2, 'o': 2}
```

Comment: I will go ahead and try this now. One other question I is regarding your for loop. I noticed a lot people who seem to know what they are doing use the loop format like you did here: "letter: sample.count(letter) for letter in letters." Is it better to do it like this or just easier to read. When I read it this way it seems a little more intuitive to thought --> do this for this in this.

Comment: @Ekko yes, it's more intuitive for simple operations and is the recommended way, but it can get messy for complex loops, in that case, it's preferred a traditional loop. Also, it's arguably faster than traditional loops too.